# How to configure ‘‑‑enable_orc_scanner’ to ture in cloudera manager 6.3, my impala version is 3.2

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, orc

In cdh6.3.0, the version of impala is 3.2. Impala can support files in ORC format, but you need to set ‑enable_orc_scanner to true.

How do I set this property in the Cloudera manager console?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Impala documentation](http://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_config_options.html) you need to add that flag, possibly to `IMPALA_SERVER_ARGS` environment variable on the Impala Daemons.

I'm not sure Cloudera Manager exposes such settings.

Note: Just because you have Cloudera Manager, does not mean you can configure each little detail on the nodes; you might need to SSH to individual machines.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I found this configuration file on the server side, but how to add this configuration, can you give me a sample, I am a novice. 
`
IMPALA_SERVER_ARGS=" \ 
-log_dir=${IMPALA_LOG_DIR} \ 
-catalog_service_host=${IMPALA_CATALOG_SERVICE_HOST} \ 
-state_store_port=${IMPALA_STATE_STORE_PORT} \ 
-use_statestore \ 
-state_store_host=${IMPALA_STATE_STORE_HOST} \ 
-be_port=${IMPALA_BACKEND_PORT}" 
`

Comment: Add a space at the very end within the quotes. Add your property. Learn bash, if you really want to understand it (Hadoop skills require knowing the basics anyway)

Answer (score 0):

In **Cloudera Manager**, navigate to **Clusters** > **Impala**.

In the Configuration tab, set `--enable_orc_scanner=true` in the Impala Command Line Argument Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve)field

[image]